# Python Regex: Multiple "start" terms, but it should only match from the last "start" term before the "end" term

Tags: python, regex

From the following string:

```
s = "ABCD {DB_any_alphanumeric_character\} ABCD {DB_any_alphanumeric_character}.TABLE ABCD"
```

I would like to match only `{DB_any_alphanumeric_character}.TABLE`. So the starting term is `{DB_` and the end term is `.TABLE`. My difficulties arise since there are two `{DB_` in the string.

**How can I make it match only from the second `{DB_` until `.TABLE`?**

I feel like this can't be a very complicated regex, but despite reading through dozens of regex related stackoverflow questions and tutorials (e.g. https://regex101.com, https://regexone.com/lesson/line_beginning_end, ...) online, I fail.

Here are just two of my unsuccessful attempts:

```
exp = re.search(r"^{DB\w*TABLE$", s)
```

It returns None. They way I see it, it should return a string that starts with `{DB` followed by zero or more repititions of any alphanumeric character and end with `TABLE`.

Another attempt:

```
test = re.search(r"{DB(.+?).TABLE", s)
```

This returns `{DB_ABCD\\} ABCD {DB_ABCD}.TABLE`, which is exactly what I don't want.

Comment: The `^` and `$` symbols assert start and end positions. Your first search will only match `{DB...TABLE` if that is the entire contents of the string.

Comment: Use: `re.findall(r'{DB_\w*}\.TABLE', s)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex `"{DB_\w*}.TABLE"` that will return only the table name that followed by .TABLE

```
import re

s = "ABCD {DB_any_alphanumeric_character\} ABCD {DB_any_alphanumeric_character}.TABLE ABCD"
exp = re.search(r"{DB_\w*}.TABLE", s)
print(exp.group(0))
```

Output

```
'{DB_any_alphanumeric_character}.TABLE'
```